# Handsontable checkbox's not working

Tags: handsontable

Real simple, I've been trying to get the checkbox type to render on my list, but all I get is the value "no." Here's my settings object. Am I doing something wrong? The list renders perfectly and works properly in terms of conditional coloring, etc., just no checkboxes. HELP! and thank you.

```
settings = {
    data: bulkListData
    ,dataSchema: {name: {first: null, last: null}, email: null,status: null,action: null}
    ,colHeaders: ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email','Status','Action']
    ,columns: [
        {data: 'name.first'},
        {data: 'name.last'},
        {data: 'email'},
        {data: 'status'},
        {data: 'action'
            ,type: 'checkbox'
            ,checkedTemplate: 'yes'
            ,uncheckedTemplate: 'no'
            }
        ]
    ,colWidths:[200,200,300,120,120]
    ,startRows: 5
    ,startCols: 5
    ,minRows: 5
    ,minCols: 5
    ,maxRows: 10
    ,maxCols: 5
    ,minSpareRows: 5
    ,autoWrapRow:true
    ,contextMenu: true}
```

Comment: post the jsfiddle? is the issue that it's not rendering the actual checkbox? you never set the renderer to use the checkbox renderer, that may be the issue

Comment: I've been checking the examples at the Handsontable.com site, and mine is identical. I don't see them doing a renderer. I did include the cellTypes.js from the src folder. My example is PHP based.

Comment: yeah no you're right, you shouldn't need to customize the renderer, though it will help you debug. Can you just post an example bulkListData? It's still a good idea to put a jsfiddle so we can modify it directly and once we have the soultion, show you

Comment: I'll put together a fiddle tomorrow. I did remove all the data, and it still doesn't render a checkbox. So odd. Will continue slicing and dicing and report back my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your sample code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvtah6mp/) and it works for me.

The only thing I needed was to fill in the `bulkListData` accordingly, otherwise everything is exactly like yours. Perhaps you are making the mistake exactly there - are your `action` properties in this array in the form of `yes`/`no` string?

Comment: I'm finding that the post render function is the culprit. When removed, I got the checkboxes. Not sure why that would be the case. I'm just color coding td's based on a single column value.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a working fiddle of your code (with the post render function), as suggested, and we'll try to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a renderer that changes the color of a column.  When this renderer is used the check boxes change to 'yes'/'no'.
When the renderer is not used the checkboxes show.

```
  $(document).ready(function () { function getCompData() {
return [
  {Comp: "Annually", year: 2006, Retirement: 'yes'},
  {Comp: "Monthly", year: 2008, Retirement: 'yes'},
  {Comp: "Quarterly", year: 2011,  Retirement: 'no'},
  {Comp: "Semi-Annually", year: 2004,  Retirement: 'yes'},
  {Comp: "Semi-Monthly", year: 2011, Retirement: 'no'}
];}function cellColorRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
          Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
          if (col === 1) {
              td.style.textAlign = 'right';
              td.style.backgroundColor = "#ccffcc";             
              }
          }var example2 = document.getElementById('example2');  var hot2 = new Handsontable(example2,{    data: getCompData(),
startRows: 7,
startCols: 4,
colHeaders: ["Comp", "Year", "401K"],
colWidths: [120, 50, 60],
columnSorting: true,
columns: [
  {
    data: "Comp"
  },
  {
    data: "year",
    type: 'numeric'
  },
  {
    data: "Retirement",
    type: "checkbox",
    checkedTemplate: 'yes',
    uncheckedTemplate: 'no'
  }
], cells: 
                function (row, col, prop) {
                    var cellProperties = {};
                    cellProperties.renderer = cellColorRenderer;
                    return cellProperties;
                },  }); });
```

Here is the code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/w42cp1y8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just use CheckboxRenderer instead TextRenderer:

```
$element.handsontable( { 
    cells: function( row, col, prop ) {
        return {
            renderer: function( instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties ) {
                Handsontable.renderers.CheckboxRenderer.apply( this, arguments );
                td.style.backgroundColor = value ? 'red' : 'white';
                td.style.textAlign = 'center';
            },
            type: 'checkbox'
        };
    }
} );
```

Comment: Might explain this a little, quote some documentation perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

jExcel is an alternative to handsontable. The example below is using a checkbox column type:

```js
data = [
    ['Brazil', 'Classe A', 'Cheese', 1, '2017-01-12'],
    ['Canada', 'Classe B', 'Apples', 1, '2017-01-12'],
    ['USA', 'Classe A', 'Carrots', 1, '2017-01-12'],
    ['UK', 'Classe C', 'Oranges', 0, '2017-01-12'],
];

$('#my').jexcel({
    data:data,
    colHeaders:  [ 'Country', 'Description', 'Type', 'Stock', 'Next purchase' ],
    colWidths: [ 300, 80, 100, 60, 120 ],
    columns: [
        { type: 'text' },
        { type: 'text' },
        { type: 'dropdown', source:[ {'id':'1', 'name':'Fruits'}, {'id':'2', 'name':'Legumes'}, {'id':'3', 'name':'General Food'} ] },
        { type: 'checkbox' },
        { type: 'calendar' },
    ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jexcel/1.2.2/css/jquery.jexcel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jexcel/1.2.2/js/jquery.jexcel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jexcel/1.2.2/js/jquery.jcalendar.min.js"></script>


<div id="my"></div>
```